# Smallest n-bit integer c that has k 1-bits and is the sum of two n-bit integers that have g, h bits set to 1(dynamic programming)

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, top-down

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Find the smallest n-bit integer c that has k 1-bits and is the sum of two n-bit integers that have g, h bits set to 1. g, h, k <= n

To start with, n-bit integer here means that we may use all `n` bits, i.e. max. value of such an integer is `2^n - 1`. The described integer may not exist at all.
It is obvious the case `k > g + h` has no solutions and for `g + h = k` the answer is just `2^k - 1` (first `k` bits are 1-bits, `k - n` zeroes in the front).

As for some examples of what the program is supposed to do:

```
g = h = k = 4, n = 10 :
0000001111 + 0000001111 = 0000011110
15 + 15 = 30 (30 should be the output)


(4, 6, 5, 10):
0000011110 + 0000111111 = 0001011101
30 + 63 = 93

(30, 1, 1, 31):
1 + (2^30 - 1) = 2^30
```

As I think of it, this is a dynamic programming problem and I've chosen the following approach: 
Let `dp[g][h][k][n][c]` be the described integer and `c` is an optional bit for carrying. I try to reconstruct possible sums depending on the lowest-order bits.
So, `dp[g][h][k][n + 1][0]` is the minimum of

```
(0, 0):       dp[g][h][k][n][0]
(0, 0): 2^n + dp[g][h][k - 1][n][1]
(1, 0): 2^n + dp[g - 1][h][k - 1][n][0]
(0, 1): 2^n + dp[g][h - 1][k - 1][n][0]
```

Similarly, `dp[g][h][k][n + 1][1]` is the minimum of

```
(1, 1): dp[g - 1][h - 1][k][n][0]
(1, 1): dp[g - 1][h - 1][k - 1][n][1] + 2^n
(1, 0): dp[g - 1][h][k][n][1]
(0, 1): dp[g][h - 1][k][n][1]
```

The idea isn't that hard but I'm not really experienced with such things and my algorithm doesn't work even for simplest cases. I've chosen top-down approach. It's hard for me to consider all the corner cases. I do not really know if I've properly chosen base of recursion, etc. My algorithm doesn't even work for the most basic case for `g = h = k = 1, n = 2`(the answer is `01 + 01 = 10`). There shouldn't be an answer for `g = h = k = 1, n = 1` but the algorithm gives `1`(which is basically why the former example outputs `1` instead of `2`).
So, here goes my awful code(only very basic C++):

```
int solve(int g, int h, int k, int n, int c = 0) {
  if (n <= 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (dp[g][h][k][n][c]) {
    return dp[g][h][k][n][c];
  }
  if (!c) {
    if (g + h == k) {
      return dp[g][h][k][n][c] = (1 << k) - 1;
    }
    int min, a1, a2, a3, a4;
    min = a1 = a2 = a3 = a4 = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    if (g + h > k && k <= n - 1) {
      a1 = solve(g, h, k, n - 1, 0);
    }
    if (g + h >= k - 1 && k - 1 <= n - 1) {
      a2 = (1 << (n - 1)) + solve(g, h, k - 1, n - 1, 1);
    }
    if (g - 1 + h >= k - 1 && k - 1 <= n - 1) {
      a3 = (1 << (n - 1)) + solve(g - 1, h, k - 1, n - 1, 0);
    }
    if (g + h - 1 >= k - 1 && k - 1 <= n - 1) {
      a4 = (1 << (n - 1)) + solve(g, h - 1, k - 1, n - 1, 0);
    }
    min = std::min({a1, a2, a3, a4});
    return dp[g][h][k][n][c] = min;
  } else {
    int min, a1, a2, a3, a4;
    min = a1 = a2 = a3 = a4 = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    if (g - 2 + h >= k && k <= n - 1) {
      a1 = solve(g - 1, h - 1, k, n - 1, 0);
    }
    if (g - 2 + h >= k - 1 && k - 1 <= n - 1) {
      a2 = (1 << (n - 1)) + solve(g - 1, h - 1, k - 1, n - 1, 1);
    }
    if (g - 1 + h >= k && k <= n - 1) {
      a3 = solve(g - 1, h, k, n - 1, 1);
    }
    if (g - 1 + h >= k && k <= n - 1) {
      a4 = solve(g, h - 1, k, n - 1, 1);
    }
    min = std::min({a1, a2, a3, a4});
    return dp[g][h][k][n][c] = min;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice question. But I believe you jump too fast to the wrong conclusion (using dynamic programming). I'd look for a more constructive approach. By solving a few cases, like 1 <= k, g, h <= 3, by hand, you may notice a pattern. Nitpick: "max. value of such an integer is `2^(n + 1) - 1`" - it is `2^n - 1` actually.

Comment: @Gassa .  If you are hinting that for g + h = k + 1 the solution is 10 +  k ones, for  g + h = k + 2  it is 110 + k ones and so on,  you are wrong. Firstly, there is a bit more comples pattern for g + h - k> k. Secondly, both of them have counterexamples!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a specific pattern in mind. Rather, a general investigation method which would reveal the pattern - or its non-existence, if that is indeed the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct the smallest sum based on the bit counts g, h, and k, without doing any dynamic programming at all. Assuming that g ≥ h (switch them otherwise) these are the rules:

**k ≤ h ≤ g**

```
      11111111  <-  g ones  
  111100000111  <-  h-k ones + g-k zeros + k ones
 1000000000110  <-  n must be at least h+g-k+1
```

**h ≤ k ≤ g**

```
    1111111111  <-  g ones  
      11111100  <-  h ones + k-h zeros
    1011111011  <-  n must be at least g+1
```

**h ≤ g ≤ k**

```
 1111111100000  <-  g ones + k-g ones  
 1100000011111  <-  g+h-k ones, k-h zeros, k-g ones
11011111111111  <-  n must be at least k+1, or k if g+h=k
```

Example: all values of k for n=10, g=6 and h=4:

```
k=1           k=2           k=3           k=4       
0000111111    0000111111    0000111111    0000111111
0111000001    0011000011    0001000111    0000001111
----------    ----------    ----------    ----------
1000000000    0100000010    0010000110    0001001110
```

```
k=4           k=5           k=6
0000111111    0000111111    0000111111
0000001111    0000011110    0000111100
----------    ----------    ----------
0001001110    0001011101    0001111011
```

```
k=6           k=7           k=8           k=9           k=10
0000111111    0001111110    0011111100    0111111000    1111110000
0000111100    0001110001    0011000011    0100000111    0000001111
----------    ----------    ----------    ----------    ----------
0001111011    0011101111    0110111111    1011111111    1111111111
```

Or, going straight to the value of c without calculating a and b first:

**k ≤ h ≤ g**

```
c = (1 << (g + h - k)) + ((1 << k) - 2)
```

**h ≤ k ≤ g**

```
c = (1 << g) + ((1 << k) - 1) - (1 << (k - h))
```

**h ≤ g ≤ k**

```
c = ((1 << (k + 1)) - 1) - (1 << ((g - h) + 2 * (k - g)))
```

**h + g = k**

```
c = (1 << k) - 1
```

which results in this disappointingly mundane code:

```
int smallest_sum(unsigned n, unsigned g, unsigned h, unsigned k) {
    if (g < h) {unsigned swap = g; g = h; h = swap;}
    if (k == 0) return (g > 0 || h > 0 || n < 1) ? -1 : 0;
    if (h == 0) return (g != k || n < k) ? -1 : (1 << k) - 1;
    if (k <= h) return (n <= h + g - k) ? -1 : (1 << (g + h - k)) + ((1 << k) - 2);
    if (k <= g) return (n <= g) ? -1 : (1 << g) + ((1 << k) - 1) - (1 << (k - h));
    if (k < g + h) return (n <= k) ? -1 : (1 << (k + 1)) - 1 - (1 << (2 * k - g - h));
    if (k == g + h) return (n < k) ? -1 : (1 << k) - 1;
    return -1;
}
```

Some example results:

```
n=31, g=15, h=25, k=10  ->  1,073,742,846  (1000000000000000000001111111110)
n=31, g=15, h=25, k=20  ->     34,602,975  (0000010000011111111111111011111)
n=31, g=15, h=25, k=30  ->  2,146,435,071  (1111111111011111111111111111111)
```

*(I compared the results with those of a brute-force algorithm for every value of n, g, h and k from 0 to 20 to check correctness, and found no differences.)*

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too convinced about the dynamic programming approach. If I understand correctly, you would need to define how to go to `dp[g + 1][h][k][n]`, `dp[g][h + 1][k][n]`, `dp[g][h][k + 1][n]` and `dp[g][h][k][n + 1]`, with and without the carry bit, in function of previous computations, and I'm not sure about what are the right rules for all of those.

I think an easier way to think of the problem is as an [A* search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) tree, where each node contains two partial candidate numbers to add, let's call them G and H. You start with a node with G = 0 and H = 0 at level m = 0, and work as follows:

1. If G + H has n or fewer bits and k 1 bits, that's the solution, you found it!
2. Otherwise, if
   n - m  < number of 1 bits in G + H  - k
   discard the node (no solution possible).
3. Otherwise, if
   (g + h) - (number of 1 bits in G + number of 1 bits in H) < k - number of 1 bits in G + H
   discard the node (not viable candidates).
4. Otherwise, branch the node into a new level. Generally you make up to four children of each node, prefixing G and H with 0 and 0, 0 and 1, 1 and 0 or 1 and 1 respectively. However:

   - You can only precede G with a 1 if the number of 1 bits in G is fewer than g, and similarly for H and h.
   - At level m (G and H have m bits), you can only precede G with a 0 if
     n - m > g - number of 1 bits in G
     and similarly for H and h.
   - If G == H and g == h, you can skip one of 0 and 1 and 1 and 0, since they will lead to the same subtree.
5. Continue to the next node and repeat until you find a solution or you don't have any more nodes to visit.

The order in which you visit the nodes is important. You should store the nodes in a priority queue/heap such that the next node is always the first node that could potentially lead to the best solution. This is actually easy, you just need to take for each node G + H and prefix it with the necessary number of 1 bits to reach k; that's the best possible solution from there.

There are possibly better rules to discard invalid nodes (steps 2 and 3), but the idea of the algorithm is the same.

Comment: Thanks, the idea is great. However, I do  not really understand how to implement 'A*-ness' here. What should be the keys for the priority queue, namely edge weight(presumably = 1 for all edges) and heuristic weight. Prefixing with the needed number of 1-bits would give the number but there's no guarantee that this is the sum of two integers with g, h 1-bits. Moreover, the role of such prefixing for the priority queue/heap seems to be obscure

Comment: @Atin The weight for the min-heap would be that prefixed value. Like you said, there is no guarantee that you will be able to reach that number from a given node, but you have the guarantee that you will not possibly reach a better solution (that is, it is an optimistic heuristic), which is what A* requires to work (obviously, the more accurate the optimistic heuristic the better).

Comment: Oh, I see. However, this approach neglects edge weights making it a greedy best-first search rather than A* search. Are edge weights implicit or it is indeed best-first search? Just making sure I understood everything correctly. @jdehesa

Comment: @Atin To be honest I'm not really sure what you mean by "edge weights"... You should only need a priority queue for the nodes sorted by the optimistic estimation and pick the best possible next node on each iteration (which does not need to be a child of the previous visited node). The tree is more of an abstraction to think about the algorithm. The first result will always be the best, but that doesn't mean it's greedy; the algorithm will reach nodes with no possible solution and then just pick another possible node from the queue (sort of backtracking, although not in a predefined order).